# How to access group folders / shared folders from EWS (ExchangeService) in C#

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

How do I access group folders / shared folders from EWS (ExchangeService) - I can access my own folders - no problem - but I cannot see Mailboxes I have access to such as Team Mailboxes or group mailboxes.

I Can get my own folders this way:

```cs
ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService();
_service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MY Username", "My Password");
_service.AutodiscoverUrl("My Email Address",delegate(string x) { return true; });

FolderView view = new FolderView(int.MaxValue);  
view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Shallow;
FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(id, view);
```

The above will only give my OWN stuff. Question is how do I get the rest of the Mailboxes that I have access to, and can see from within Outlook ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the mailbox name then [`DistinguishedFolderIdType.Mailbox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchangewebservices.distinguishedfolderidtype.mailbox%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) may be what you're looking for. See [this SO post regarding using delegates in EWS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/268104/175679).

Here is an example of accessing a [shared Exchange Mailbox](http://arturito.net/2010/06/14/c-sharp-accesing-shared-mailbox-in-exchange-web-services-2007-service-pack-1-and-downloading-attachments/) via [`FolderId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folderid%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) and [`Mailbox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.mailbox%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I dont anything about the name nor the ID of the Mailbox'es. All I know is that I have one or more Mailbox'es that are shared with me. It must be possible to use EWS to get these - an example would be nice !

Comment: Indeed, Outlook seems to do this, so why couldn't you do this with the EWS?